# Proving the solutions to an Equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Consider:

[image: Problem for proof]

I am sort of confused. Without using the intermediate value theorem, **directly.** I suppose **indirect** use if fine.

$1 + x^2 + \sin^2(x) > 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Let the $LHS = I$

$$I = x^{179} + \frac{163}{1+x^2 + \sin^2(x)} = 119$$

$$\frac{x^{179} + x^{181} + x^{179}\sin^2(x) + 163}{1 + x^2 + \sin^2(x)} = 119$$

$$   \frac{ \left|x^{179} + x^{181} + x^{179}\sin^2(x) + 163  \right|}{1 + x^2 + \sin^2(x)}  < \left|x^{179} + x^{181} + x^{179}\sin^2(x) + 163  \right| $$

Actually, I dont think that was necessary. One of spivak's proofs is:

$$a_0 + ... + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + a_{n}x^n = c$$

Then there exists a solution for $c \ge m$ and not for $c < m$ where $m$ is a number.

Comment: That last line of your is not at all clear. Taken at face value, it is false. If $n$ is odd, there is a solution for any $c$.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Do you want a proof using the intermediate value theorem or one without it? For one with it, look at the left-hand side for $x$ approaching $-\infty$ and for $x$ approaching $+\infty$: the values go from very small to very large, passing by $119$ at some point.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, thats how the question is given.

Comment: My confusions are in your lines "Without using..." and "Then there exists...", not in the question in the graphic. The meanings of those lines are not clear to me.